# Multillingual column name becomes internal name

Tags: column, multilingual

I have a problem where a column used by a couple of content types is correctly named `Document version` when the user views the page in Swedish, but the display names becomes the internal name `Document_x0020_version` when viewing the exact same Document library in English.

[image]

Anyone know how to deal with this?